# How do I show that a statement is true (Discrete Math)

Tags: logic

How do i show that this statement is true?

> $$\forall x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}\space \space xSy \wedge zSw \implies (x+z)S(y+w)$$

The relation S is defined with:

> $$ xSy \Leftrightarrow (x + y \textrm{  is even} \wedge x \leq y )$$

Comment: What are $Z$ and $S$?

Comment: What does $S$ mean? [$Z$ usually means the integers, so are we doing  arithmetic? But in arithmetic, $S$ is very often the successor relation -- and this statement is false.]

Comment: Sorry for begin stupid :/ I added the definition of S. Z means the integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that $(x+z)+(y+w)$ is even and $x+z\le y+w$, given that $x+y$ and $z+w$ are even, $x\le y,$ and $z\le w$. The first one should be simple, since $$(x+z)+(y+w)=x+z+y+w=x+y+z+w=(x+y)+(z+w).$$ For the second one, you'll start with $x+z$. Since $z\le w,$ then $x+z\le x+w$. What can you say about the order relationship between $x+w$ and $y+w$? What can you conclude, then, by transitivity of order?

Comment: That x + w $\leq$ y + w
I'm not entirely sure what I should conclude.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Since $x+z\le x+w$ and $x+w\le y+w,$ what can you conclude?

Comment: I'm not sure what I should conclude, do you mean something like x + z $\leq$ y + w

Comment: Exactly! That finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

if

```
A and C => X
```

and

```
B and D => Y
```

then

```
(A and C) and (B and D) => X and Y
```

More strong hint:

What do we have?

```
x + y is even and x ≤ y
z + w is even and z ≤ w
```

What should we get?

```
x + y + z + w is even and x + z ≤ y + w
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit further, because I'm not exactly sure how this hint is helping me.

Comment: fixed first hint a bit, added 1 more